# Fast way to find out the ISSN number of Publications

Tags: publications

I like to know can i get the Publications [ISSN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Serial_Number) form [DOI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier) link?

Or what is the fast way to find the **ISSN** of Publications to find its impact factor ( any online site to find the impact factor for **DOI** link or ...)

**Update:** (**Solved**)

According the [anpami](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/120630/anpami)  answer i have tried to do it for [this](https://doi.org/10.1109/CIMCA.2018.8739662) paper, and don't find any **ISSN** number on the [result](https://api.crossref.org/works/doi.org/10.1109/CIMCA.2018.8739662):

[image]

And importing on [this](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer):

[image]

So does ISSN not exist for conference and only of journals or this answer is not correct?(**Solved** based on the **anpami** comment)

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Buffy, i updated the question and corrected it.

Comment: In your case, the paper is not a journal publication, but a paper presented at a conference. Conference proceedings, however, do *not* necessarily have an ISSN (see here: https://support.clarivate.com/ScientificandAcademicResearch/s/article/Web-of-Science-Core-Collection-Conference-Proceedings-May-Have-ISSN-or-ISBN?language=en_US). - And: You originally asked how to fetch the ISSN with the help of a DOI so as to get the Impact Factor. Note that conferences do not have Impact Factors, only journals do.

Comment: Thanks, @anpami, so i will add solved to last part of question.

Answer (score 4):

To get the ISSN of a paper by using the paper's DOI, try [CrossRef's API](https://github.com/CrossRef/rest-api-doc). Specifically, use the URL https://api.crossref.org/works/ and add the DOI to it.

For example, if the DOI is 10.1177/0047117819856397,
then use the URL https://api.crossref.org/works/10.1177/0047117819856397

There is a branch called "ISSN" in that JSON-file. If the output looks confusing to you, copy-paste it into a '[JSON beautifier](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer)'.

(However, note that you cannot find the Impact Factor of the journal using this approach; as far as I know, there is no API for accessing an Impact Factor by using the ISSN as a key. Also see "[Where can I find the Impact Factor for a given journal?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3/where-can-i-find-the-impact-factor-for-a-given-journal/149540#149540)")