# Which website contains impact factors of all journals?

Tags: journals, bibliometrics

Impact factor for individual journals can be found on their website. There are several impact factors in use, like the 2-5 years impact factor, real-time impact factor (i.e., monthly update), Scimago impact factor.

I have found [Academic Accelator](https://academic-accelerator.com/Journal-Profile/Duke-Mathematical-Journal) which provides the 2-5 years impact factor and the real-time impact factor (i.e., monthly update). Then there is [Scimago journal ranking](https://www.scimagojr.com/journalsearch.php?q=21100389312&tip=sid) which also contains the citation impact factor and classification of journals into four categories Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4. Then there is another place called [Resurchify](https://www.resurchify.com/impact/details/21100389312) which also reports journal impact factors.

Which website is an authentic source that contains impact factor of all scientific journals ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find the Impact Factor for a given journal?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3/where-can-i-find-the-impact-factor-for-a-given-journal)

Comment: Well, nobody reports an impact factor for my personally-curated in-house boutique scientific journal. The fact that I've only published one issue and stuffed the only copy in my bottom desk drawer is no excuse...  Anyway, it seems to me that you have already noticed that many places report many different 'impact factors' of a variety of journals. There is no one true universal reporting place.

Comment: @Sursulasupportsthestrike, it answer my question somewhat. Yet I want to know about the authenticity of [academic accelator](https://academic-accelerator.com/Journal-Profile/Duke-Mathematical-Journal). Is it good source ?

Comment: @learner I don't even know what "authentic" is supposed to mean in that context. Everyone can define any kind of impact factor and publish it somewhere. Does that make it "true"?

Comment: @Sursulasupportsthestrike, authentic means those are believed to be correct impact factor..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only journals that have *impact factors* are those indexed by Clarivate's Web of Science, as they calculate and release the annual Journal Citation Report (as J.P. mentioned already) containing that metric. Thus, only the official impact factors contained in that report are "authentic". But as you have found, there are a handful of other citation metrics including Scimago Journal Ranking, CiteScore, Source-normalized Impact per Paper (SNIP), and others. Each of these metrics is slightly different and not directly comparable to each other or to impact factor. You can certainly use them and some may actually be better than IF, but they are not the same thing. Importantly, they are not inauthentic or incorrect, just different.

It's worth noting that sometimes sketchy journals will advertise these metrics *in place* of a an IF, watch out for that. Having (or not having) an impact factor doesn't mean a journal is good or bad, but lying about it (or trying to pass off another metric as an IF) is suspicious. On top of that, sometimes aggregate websites are not particularly careful about reporting IF and will scrape *any* citation metric and add it in that place.

Unless you have Clarivate's JCR, you have to rely on journal-reported impact factors. And any free website aggregating these (unless they have access to the original report) are probably scrapping the IFs from the internet. So again, they are not necessarily inauthentic. They may be outdated, misreported, or in the case of predatory journals, made up though. So really all of those websites are reasonable ways to try to quickly compare impact factors (or other metrics) but be aware that you'll need to verify the info that they provide. As far as I know the only way to have the complete list of impact factors would be to purchase the JCR at the source.

Answer (score 4):

Typically, the term "impact factor" refers specifically to the trademarked journal index owned by Clarivate. It is released annually as part of the publication Journal Citation Reports, which is available at [jcr.clarivate.com](https://jcr.clarivate.com) and requires a subscription to access.